# Capybara Selector for a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, cucumber, capybara, selector

I have the following code HTML and I am not sure if it is possible to build a selector for "find" in capybara to get the element I need. I'm using capybara for cucumber in a rails project. (The HTML is generated)

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Heine</td>
    <td><a href="/customers/1">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/customers/1/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/customers/1">Destroy</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IKEA</td>
    <td><a href="/customers/2">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/customers/2/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/customers/2">Destroy</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testcustomer</td>
    <td><a href="/customers/5">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/customers/5/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/customers/5">Destroy</a></td>
  </tr>
```

How can I "find" the href "edit" for the row where th first td contains "testcutomer"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

```
find("td", :text => /\Atestcustomer\z/).first(:xpath,"..").find("a", :text => /\AEdit\z/)
```

`find("td", :text => /\Atestcustomer\z/)` gives you the `td` with the text "testcustomer", then you find the parent of that `td` using `first(:xpath,"..")` then you find anchor tag with text "Edit" using `find("a", :text => /\AEdit\z/)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the racktest driver this can be done pretty clearly taking advantage of the fact that in nokogiri css selectors can be started with a sibling selector and it will be interpreted in the scope of the element find is being called on.

```
find(:css, 'td', text: 'testcustomer').find(:css, '~ td > a', text: 'Edit')
```

If using any "real browser" driver that will probably not be allowed since the spec for querySelector doesn't allow for it.  In that case this is most easily done using xpath (note this will also work with racktest so is the preferred solution for cross driver compatability) with the following-sibling axis

```
find(:xpath, ".//td[text()='testcustomer']/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Edit']")
```